# Получаю ошибки при использовании курсора в plsql

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, apex

Пытаюсь выполнить задание:

> Составьте сценарий, в котором создайте новую таблицу для
> занесения имен продавцов и минимальных стоимостей их заказов.
> В сценарии измените параметры последовательности из
> Задания 4 так, чтобы она формировала четные числа, начиная
> с 5000. Используя курсор, заполните созданную таблицу,
> причем, при вставке строк для формирования уникальных
> значений идентификаторов примените свою последовательность.
> Сценарий должен заканчиваться выводом данных из
> заполненной таблицы. Выполните сценарий.

[результаты выполнения сценария](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlKJF.png)

Не могу справиться с данными ошибками.

```
DROP TABLE sal_amt;
DROP SEQUENCE seq_num;
CREATE TABLE sal_amt(i NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
sname VARCHAR2(10),
min_amt NUMBER(7,2));
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_num INCREMENT BY 2 START WITH 5000;
DECLARE 
CURSOR m_sal IS
SELECT sal.sname, MIN(ord.amt) amt FROM ord INNER JOIN sal ON ord.snum = sal.snum GROUP BY ord.snum;
BEGIN
 FOR v_am IN m_sal 
 LOOP
 INSERT INTO sal_amt(i, sname, min_amt) VALUES (seq_num.NEXTVAL, v_am.sname, v_am.amt);
 END LOOP;
END; 
/
SELECT * FROM sal_amt;
```

Comment: Так и с чем конкретно у вас возникла проблема? Вы скобки не можете посчитать?

Comment: Просто опечатка, если ее убрать, то лучше не становится. Проблема с group by "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression ORA-06512: at line 3 ORA-06512: at line 5 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721"

Comment: _то лучше не становится_, нет, становится лучше, уже одной опечаткой меньше, устраните просто следующую опечатку.

Comment: Какую? Не вижу там больше опечаток.

Comment: `sal.sname, ... GROUP BY ord.snum`, если это не опечатка, то поясните, что вы пытаетесь этим добится.

Comment: сгруппировать по номерам продавцов, чтобы получить выборку с минимальным заказом и именем для каждого из них

Comment: И каким именем, вы же не группируете по этому столбцу?  Добавте sal.sname в GROUP BY.

Comment: Спасибо, не знала о том, что группировка именно по полям из select